# Why can't I select radio button using Selenium? Button is highlighted, but not selected

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I use C# with Internet Explorer 8.

I have the following code for a radio button:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("optNoteReplace")));
driver.FindElement(By.Id("optNoteReplace")).Click();
```

When I single-step through the code, the Click command is silently executed, and the next line is highlighted. There is no error, but the radio button is not selected.

Immediately after the line of code is executed, a small faint square appears round the radio button. I think that proves that the correct radio button is selected.

If I alter the line of code to select the other radio button, the square disappears from the first button, and reappears round the second button.

I would be grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Can I see code of element with id="optNoteReplace"?

Comment: Vlad:  I'm assuming you mean HTML. If not, please let me know:  `<input name="optNoteAddOrReplace" id="optNoteReplace" type="radio" value="Replace"/>`

Comment: Some kind posters on this forum, and other forums, have very generously provided about 20 different pieces of "wait" code. At this time, I'm only interested in trying to click a radio button. I have no interest in wait code. Here's the reason. I'm not a techie. I'm asked to run a few tests for only a few hours each week. Speed of execution is not an issue. I run all code from within the C# Visual Studio Express IDE using F5 and F10, with breakpoints. When an error occurs, the offending line is highlighted yellow...(more)

Comment: ...If there's a timeout, I simply hit F10 or F5 until there's no timeout error   After I find out how to click the radio button, I will go back later and add appropriate wait code.

Comment: Please, assure, that there is only one element with this Id. Also, try to click it using e.g. value property.

Comment: Vlad. Summary so far with new stuff. (1) Only one element with name, value. (2) Latest code: `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("#optNoteReplace"))); IWebElement RadioReplace = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[value='Replace']")); Assert.AreEqual(RadioReplace.Selected, false); driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();RadioReplace.Click();Thread.Sleep(10000);Assert.AreEqual(RadioReplace.Selected, true); // assert fails` (3) Without driver.SwitchTo, code never works. With driver.SwitchTo, code works randomly about 80% of the time. (4) ....(more)

Comment: Vlad (continued). (4) Always get faint square round correct radio button. (5) IE zoom = 100% (6) Is there code that allows me to SET the attribute to "Selected", rather than use "Click()"?

Comment: I'm not sure it is the best way to resolve this situation, but yes, you can check it in code using javascript: document.getElementsByClassName('yourClassName')[0].checked=true;    where [0] is a serial number of element in chosen array.

Comment: Vlad. Following javascript code works: `js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor; js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", RadioReplace);` Thanks for your help and interest :)

Answer (score 0):

pay attention to the css selector or xPAth using which you try to locate the radiobutton with.
I usually use firepath (firebug addon in ffox)
[image: firepath validation]

That worked for me in java:

```
@Test
    public void radioButtonCheck(){
        driver.get("http://www.abw.by/index.php?act=finance");

        fluentWait(By.cssSelector("html body div table#main_tb tbody tr td#main_td01 div.block table tbody tr td noindex div div table tbody tr td div:first-child>input:first-child")).click();
    }

public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
//                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement foo = wait.until(
                new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
                    }
                }
        );
        return  foo;              }     ;
```

Also try using instead wait.Until   fluent wait. Read some addition info about fluent wait [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html)

Hope this helps you)